# Understand how to use AJAX to work with smarty in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, smarty

What I am trying to do is probably very simple (the irony is I am stuck).

I have a file which smarty divides into (template and php) file. 
I have a small js script which is sending ajax request to update a variable to the (php file).

In the php file  based on what I get from the AJAX i am doing

```
$smarty->assign('test',$_GET['test'])
```

and then

```
$smarty->display('index.tpl')
```

Now since it is AJAX I am confused what to send as a response, as I am already displaying the template.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you rephrase or show a code example?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455780/smarty-and-ajax

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is very simple(irony is i am stuck in it) , I have a file which smarty divides into (template and php) file. I have a small js script which is sending ajax request to update a variable to the (php file).In the php file  based on what I get from the ajax i am doing $smarty->assign('test',$_GET['test'])    and then $smarty->display('index.tpl'), now since it is ajax I am confused  what to send as a response , as I am already displaying the template.

Comment: what format do you *need* on the Ajax side?

Comment: @pekka I just want to refresh the template as I load anothertemplate inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your application is going to do with the response of the AJAX request.

Ideally, your client-side app (in javacsript land) will be expecting data from your web service (in JSON or some other format), and then the client-side app will dynamically manipulate the html (DOM) as needed.

However, it may be likely that you simply want to take the response from the AJAX request and throw it into an html element. If this is the case, you could simply send your response in html format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Smarty guru, however this answer gives a hint as to how to use Ajax with Smarty - perhaps you can build upon this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630714/smarty-the-best-choice/632458#632458

It looks like instead of calling `$smarty->display()` you should call `echo $smarty->fetch()`

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    echo $smarty->fetch('your-file.tpl');
}
```